# Argument Type does not conform to expected type 'WKScriptMessageHandler'

Tags: swift, wkwebview, swiftui, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm trying two-way integration between Swift and Javascript interfacing with SwiftUI.
Here is interfacing WebKit with SwiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ggWebView : UIViewRepresentable {

    let filePath: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.absoluteURL
        let html = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(filePath)
        uiView.loadFileURL(html, allowingReadAccessTo:bundleURL)
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "jsHandler"{
            print(message.body)
        }
    }
}
```

`userContentController.add(self, name: "jsHandler")` shows an error at `self` with `Argument type 'ggWebView' does not conform to expected type 'WKScriptMessageHandler'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `WKScriptMessageHandler` require that object that implements it inherit from `NSObject` it is better to create a separate class `ContentController` that will be implementing those protocol, rather than changing the type of `GgWebView`.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct GgWebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let filePath: String
    let contentController = ContentController()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.configuration.userContentController.add(contentController, name: "jsHandler")
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.absoluteURL
        let html = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(filePath)
        uiView.loadFileURL(html, allowingReadAccessTo:bundleURL)
    }

    class ContentController: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
            if message.name == "jsHandler"{
                print(message.body)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You have to confirm `ggWebView` (BTW this is not the best name for a class because it should start with capital letter) to `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol and implement `func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)` method. You have to change the type of `ggWebView` from `structure` to `class`. I can see that you already add a `userContentController(_:didReceive:)` method, so you only need to update your class signature to:

```swift
class ggWebView: UIViewRepresentable, WKScriptMessageHandler {
```

Comment: Got two error: `Non-class type 'ggWebView' cannot conform to class protocol 'WKScriptMessageHandler` and `Non-class type 'ggWebView' cannot conform to class protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'`

Comment: @Lonaso try changing from `structure` to `class`

Comment: You will need also to provide `init` like: `init(filePath: String) { self.filePath = filePath }`

Comment: Can you please full working example, please? I got 4 more errors after doing that. @bazyl87

Comment: @Lonaso I've updated the answer, please let me know if it working for you

Comment: Question: How would I be able to change a @State property of GgWebView from inside the contentController instance?

Comment: just use Maciej's implementation, it works